# Color transition effect in Leaflet.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

See this example:

https://www.mapbox.com/ten-years-openstreetmap/

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Is it done by CSS transition or Leaflet API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Chrome Web inspector, you can watch how this effect is managed with TileLayers stacked on top of each other, and the CSS `opacity` attribute changing as time passes on.So it sounds like there would be some custom JS timing setup you would need to duplicate this, probably with Leaflet's `setOpacity` method on `TileLayer` - documentation at http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setopacity.

[image: Web Inspector Shot]